# abcPdf version upgrade issue [result pdf is different by passing the same html]

Tags: c#, abcpdf, html-to-pdf, abcpdf9

I am facing a strange issue. I have a html document, and to create PDF out of it, I am using abcPdf.

When I was using abcPdf v7, the resulted pdf was fine. But moving it to version abcPdf 9 making the whole thing bigger [a bit big font, hence lessar margin]

Any idea if this is an intentional upgrade implementation. And please let me know if any check is present to make it compatible with v7 generated pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to the html engine has grown in ABCpdf. Now you can choose MSHTML engine (Internet Explorer) or Gecko engine (Firefox). Maybe yoy have to explore this changes vía Engine property (http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/1-engine.htm)

But as a licensed user, send them an email, they use to reply very fast.